# How to check for the presence of alt attribute in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, w3c

I have tried using getAttribute but even if my web element has the html like 
`<img src=“abc.png”>`, where the alt attribute is missing, it adds alt=“” (an empty string instead of declaring it as null (non-existent)).

Is there a way to check for cases where the alt attribute is missing (NOT for checking if it is an empty string but if it is not existent at all in the first place). Any suggestions are appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

If `alt` attribute is not present, then img will take the default value which is "". img tag also has height and width etc. They will also take the default value of image's height and width values.

If you want to see if the attribute is explicitly present or not, you can get the value of outerHTML attribute to get `<img src=“abc.png”>` as text and see if alt attribute is present or not.